# Outputting string to console - ASM 8086

Tags: assembly, int, x86-16

I'm trying to use INT 21h to show a string on a screen, but the program seems to crash immediately...

I'm using MASM

Here's my code:

```
.stack 200h

    .data?
      value dd ?

    .data
      item dd 0
      str1 db 'Hello world!$'
    .code

start:

; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤


    mov edx, offset str1
    mov al, 09h
    int 21h
; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

end start
```

Comment: Um, you didn't tell the computer what to do after the `int 21h` returns.

Comment: well, i tried to add some like to exit program, but the program still crashes...why? (btw i use win 7 64bit)

Comment: Um, 64-bit Windows does not support MS-DOS programs.

Comment: In that case your question is wrong. The program doesn't crash at all because not a single instruction of it is executed on 64-bit Windows. Windows should give you a clear error message something like `The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system
information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher`. There's nothing about a crash in it.

Answer (score 2):

A few problems:

1. Your program doesn't exit to DOS correctly, it just lets the CPU execute whatever garbage is there in the memory after your `int 21h`. Use `function 4ch` to terminate your program.
2. Your stack may be too little. Interrupt service routines and resident programs, drivers included (and probably DOS as well), use the current stack. If they need more than `200h` bytes at any moment, they'll overwrite whatever code or data happens to be where they think there's still some stack space. That too can cause a crash or hang. Bump up the size to `1000h`.
3. You did not indicate what processor your program was run on. The problem is, you used an i80386+ instruction (`mov edx, offset str1`), which naturally isn't available on i8086/8088, i80186 and i80286 and their clones. Btw, DOS does not support 32-bit addresses or offsets. It should be `mov dx, offset str1`.

There might be something else, but let's fix these first.

Comment: Hello, It's my first program in ASM ^^, I'm using win 7 64-bit, Intel Q6600 processor.

So which asm functions should I use for console application?

Comment: In either case please provide more information on how you run the program, what errors or misbehavior you *actually* observe, how you compile the program, etc etc.

Comment: I type it all in the MASM editor, and then I press Project->Build All,
and then through cmd I open the exe file and then it crashes...

Comment: What kind of MASM editor? And I think you're making a Windows EXE (32-bit or 64-bit) instead of a DOS EXE (16-bit).

Comment: On a second thought, I doubt you can produce a 32-bit Windows EXE with segments. See if your code still compiles if you insert `mov ax, seg str1` before `mov al, 09h`. If it stops compiling after this addition, then you have been compiling a 32-bit Windows EXE without segments, which Windows could probably execute until `int 21h`, which would indeed cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly using 8086, use this:
.model small
org 100h
.data
message db "Hello World $"
.code
main proc
        mov ah,09h
        mov dx,offset message
        int 21h
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
endp
end main

Much simpler and cleaner imo.